# save HTML form to Dropbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, dropbox

I'm trying to avoid a web server. And now when people submit a form, it will be mailed to me.

the form consist of a name, last name and an email address.
My question is, is there a way when the user click submit, the data will be saved in a folder online on my dropbox.

So when a user click submit, I want a text file or an excel sheet to be created in my dropbox that hold all the information.
And is it safe to do so without risking my dropbox account ?

Comment: There's no way to do that.

Comment: Psst. http://www.google.com/forms